# Send array with vanilla Js from Ajax to Laravel controller

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, laravel, xmlhttprequest

I would like to send an array with elements to my laravel controller with vanilla JS, (I don't want to use Jquery). But I can't get it work... I found several solutions on web with trying to make a json object and so on but nothing wanted to work...

This is my code:

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

         xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                alert('sent');

         }
          };


        xhttp.open("GET", '{{route('profile.toggleCategory', $user)}}', true);

        xhttp.send(categories);
```

and my laravel controller:

```
public function toggleCategory(Request $request, User $user)
{

    dd($categories = $request->categories);

    $user->categories()->sync(collect($categories));
}
```

Comment: What aspect of your goal are you having trouble with? Is it reaching the controller, but the data is not in the format you desire?

Comment: I get "null" when i do "$request->categories", so my controller can't find the var categories.. :/

Comment: What do your user and category tables look like, and any relevant pivot tables? What do the models for both look like, and specifically the definition of the relationship? What data do you see in the database directly using phpmyadmin or sql pro or a similar tool?

Answer (score 0):

I changed a few things and now it is working!

***The working code:***

web.php:

```
Route::post('{user}/togglecategory', 'Site\ProfileController@toggleCategory')->name('toggleCategory');
```

Javascript code:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                alert('send');

         }
          };


        xhttp.open("POST", '{{route('profile.toggleCategory', $user)}}', true);

        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", document.head.querySelector("[name=csrf-token]").content );

        xhttp.send("categories="+categories);


        });
```

Laravel Controller:

```
public function toggleCategory(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $categories = explode(',', $request->categories);

        $user->categories()->sync($categories);
    }
```